# Overflow-y and Fixed Positioned Bug Fix in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, scroll, overflow, css-position

I am building a site and have a div with another div inside (lets call them div.container and div.contained). div.container is relatively positioned and div.contained has a fixed position. I want to use the overflow-y: scroll property to have the overflowing content in the container displayed within a defined height and scrollable.  I found that this is a common issue in many versions of Internet Explorer along with an article that states the quickest way to fix the bug is to make the position of div.contained relative (http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/9-most-common-ie-bugs-and-how-to-fix-them--net-7764).

I tried this workaround but changing the position style of div.contained throws off the whole website. I tried looking through the forum and have found similar issues but no specific workaround for fixed elements, just relative ones. Does anyone have any advice on how to fix this ie bug for a fixed positioned div?